# Need help using Series() transformation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and pandas. I'm doing something wrong with Series transformation that I can't spot

I have a dataframe with a date column CFB_FECHAINICIO that I format as DateTimeIndex in a new column 'fecha':

```
    df['fecha']= pd.DatetimeIndex(df.CFB_FECHAINICIO)
    df.fecha.head()
    0          2015-01-01 21:44:01
    1   2015-01-02 22:50:50.867000
    2   2015-01-05 00:26:04.387000
    3          2015-01-07 00:10:03
    4          2015-01-07 23:47:18
    Name: fecha, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

so it seems my datetime64 column index is ok.

I have another column that I want to keep in my timeseries, df.MG

```
    ts = pd.Series(df.MG.dropna())
    ts.head()
    20    4.60
    29    4.67
    33    4.41
    34    4.44
    35    4.56
    Name: MG, dtype: float64
```

but when I use 'fecha' as index, the ts values appear as NaN

```
    ts = pd.Series(df.MG.dropna(),index=df.fecha.dropna())
    ts.head()
    2015-01-02 22:50:50.867000   NaN
    2015-01-08 23:08:30          NaN
    2015-01-09 21:46:14          NaN
    2015-01-14 23:28:13          NaN
    2015-01-29 00:24:46          NaN
    Name: MG, dtype: float64
```

I have verified that all values appear as NaN, not only first ones.
Any clue of what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I've found a solution, not sure if it is the best one but it works. I post it here in case it can be of help or any of you do find a better one.

```
df.set_index('fecha',inplace=True)
ts = pd.Series(df.MG.dropna())
ts.head()
fecha
2015-01-29 00:24:46    4.60
2015-02-10 23:24:50    4.67
2015-02-17 00:20:35    4.41
2015-02-18 00:18:38    4.44
2015-02-18 22:58:48    4.56
Name: MG, dtype: float64
```

Comment: You could shorten it to `ts = df.MG.dropna()` since the right-hand side would already be a Series.